# Android Studio Doesn't Start on Ubuntu

Tags: android, android-studio

I started using Android Studio after a couple of days, Suddenly Android Studio didn't start . When I started it through terminal i.e "Studio" Command. Got the Following Error.

```
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=350m; support was removed in 8.0
Start Failed: Internal Error. Please report to https://https://code.google.com/p/android/issues

java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.ide.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:39)
    at com.intellij.idea.Main.main(Main.java:103)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_91/jre/lib/i386/libawt_xawt.so: libXrender.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1941)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1824)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:809)
    at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1086)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1941)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1845)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
    at java.awt.Toolkit$3.run(Toolkit.java:1636)
    at java.awt.Toolkit$3.run(Toolkit.java:1634)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.awt.Toolkit.loadLibraries(Toolkit.java:1633)
    at java.awt.Toolkit.<clinit>(Toolkit.java:1668)
    at java.awt.Cursor.<clinit>(Cursor.java:195)
    at javax.swing.text.html.HTMLEditorKit.<clinit>(HTMLEditorKit.java:623)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.UIUtil.<clinit>(UIUtil.java:97)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager.start(PluginManager.java:71)
    ... 6 more


Also, an UI exception occurred on attempt to show above message:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class java.awt.Toolkit
    at java.awt.Component.<clinit>(Component.java:593)
    at com.intellij.idea.Main.showMessage(Main.java:336)
    at com.intellij.idea.Main.showMessage(Main.java:312)
    at com.intellij.idea.Main.showMessage(Main.java:291)
    at com.intellij.idea.Main.main(Main.java:106)
```

I have re-installed java 7 and java 8 both . Also Reinstalled Android Studio. But still there was no help. 
I had installed octave before, was that a problem?

Comment: Are you running 32 bit ubuntu? Or installed jdk 32 bit?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24543014/shared-libraries-java-32-bit-on-64bit-ubuntu

Comment: @EugenMartynov My Ubuntu is 64 bit. and I installed Jdk x86 (jdk-8u91-linux-i586.tar.gz)

Comment: x86 is 32 bit jdk. Install 64 bit jdk as possible solution

Comment: Thanks This solved the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve the problem you should install JDK 64bit. From the comments, you have installed 32-bit JDK

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. I killed the app and reopened. It fixed the issue for me.