# wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64 (Possible cause: architecture word width mismatch)

Tags: java, serial-port, ubuntu-14.04

I am trying to run jar for Serial Communication in Ubuntu 14.04 which requires librxtxSerial.so to be in 'jdk/bin' folder. I referred below link:

[wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32 (Possible cause: architecture word width mismatch)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16188672/wrong-elf-class-elfclass32-possible-cause-architecture-word-width-mismatch)

I tried with both 32-bit/64-bit librxtxSerial.so in 'jdk/bin' but is stuck with both the below error :

```
OpenJDK Server VM warning: You have loaded library /usr/lib/jni/librxtxSerial-2.2pre1.so which might have disabled stack guard. The VM will try to fix the stack guard now.
It's highly recommended that you fix the library with 'execstack -c <libfile>', or link it with '-z noexecstack'.
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /usr/lib/jni/librxtxSerial-2.2pre1.so: /usr/lib/jni/librxtxSerial-2.2pre1.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64 (Possible cause: architecture word width mismatch) thrown while loading gnu.io.RXTXCommDriver
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /usr/lib/jni/librxtxSerial-2.2pre1.so: /usr/lib/jni/librxtxSerial-2.2pre1.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64 (Possible cause: architecture word width mismatch)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary1(ClassLoader.java:1968)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1893)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1883)
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:849)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1088)
        at gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier.<clinit>(CommPortIdentifier.java:83)
        at test.Test.main(Test.java:32)
```

Java Version : 1.7 64-bit

Ubuntu OS Release :

```
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="14.04.1 LTS, Trusty Tahr"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS"
VERSION_ID="14.04"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
```

When I tried to run it with JAVA 1.8 it gave following error

Error: Could not find or load main clas test.Test (//My jar name is Test)

Comment: The error message suggests that you are using 32-bit Java and your native library is 64-bit. Are you sure you are using 64-bit Java? The "bitness" of your JVM and your native library must match, otherwise you get errors like this one.

Comment: Show us the results of `java -version`, and also the command line you try to run.

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto
cms@RDP:~/Desktop/RDPSerialCommunication$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_131"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.6.9) (7u131-2.6.9-0ubuntu0.14.04.2)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.131-b00, mixed mode)

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto 
Below is the Output:

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/librxtxSerial.so: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/librxtxSerial.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32 (Possible cause: architecture word width mismatch) thrown while loading gnu.io.RXTXCommDriver

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/librxtxSerial.so: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/librxtxSerial.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32 (Possible cause: architecture word width mismatch)

Comment: Ok, that last error is the opposite of what you posted in your question above: it suggests you are using 64-bit Java and your native library is 32-bit. Make sure your Java and native library have the same "bitness".

Comment: @Jesper : how to check if native library is 32 bit or 64 bit ?

Comment: You can use the `file` command, for example: `file /usr/lib/jni/librxtxSerial-2.2pre1.so`. Note that the error message tells you ELFCLASS32 or ELFCLASS64 = 32-bit or 64-bit.

Comment: @Jesper: I copied this "librxtxSerial-2.2pre1.so" to path
 "/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/"  and "/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64/bin/" and tried to run my Test.jar. It gives me below exception now : 
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no rxtxSerial in java.library.path thrown while loading gnu.io.RXTXCommDriver
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no rxtxSerial in java.library.path

Comment: dpkg -l | grep rxtx gave me below result :
ii  rxtx                                                  2.2-1.1                                             amd64        Parallel communication for the Java Development Toolkit

Comment: Solved the error : removed all d rxtx libraries and then by coping librxtxSerial-2.2pre1.so to "/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/" and RXTXComm.jar to /jre/lib/ext (64 bit)
Thank you :)

Comment: @JanhaviGadkari can you please give the download link for 64 bit  librxtxSerial.so

Comment: @KhalidShah : [link](http://jlog.org/rxtx-lin.html)

Comment: @JanhaviGadkari sorry, i want the link for 64 bit libLinuxSerialParallel.so . can you provide that ?